# Prove or disprove that a piecewise complex function has a derivative at $0$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

> *Prove or disprove that the function:*
> $$ f(x+iy)=\left\{\begin{matrix} \sqrt{xy}\: \: \: \: \text{ if } \space xy\geq 0
> \\ i\sqrt{-xy}\: \: \: \: \text{ if } \space xy<  0
> \end{matrix}\right. $$
> *has a derivative at $0.$*

I'm pretty sure that the function doesn't have derivative at $0.$

I tried showing that by using Cauchy–Riemann equations:

for $\\xy \geq 0:$
$$\\u_{x}(x,y)=\frac{\sqrt{y}}{2\sqrt{x}}
\\u_{y}(x,y)=\frac{\sqrt{x}}{2\sqrt{y}}
\\v_{x}(x,y)=0
\\v_{y}(x,y)=0$$

for $\\xy \geq 0:$
$$
\\u_{x}(x,y)=0
\\u_{y}(x,y)=0
\\v_{x}(x,y)=-\frac{\sqrt{y}}{2\sqrt{-xy}}
\\v_{y}(x,y)=-\frac{\sqrt{x}}{2\sqrt{-xy}}
$$

so:
$$
\\0=\frac{\sqrt{y}}{2\sqrt{x}}
\\0=\frac{\sqrt{x}}{2\sqrt{y}}
$$
and:
$$
\\0=-\frac{\sqrt{y}}{2\sqrt{-xy}}
\\0=-\frac{\sqrt{x}}{2\sqrt{-xy}}
$$

so for $(x,y)=(0,0)$ the equations are true.

Furthermore, I tried applying the limit definition of the derivative $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}\frac{f(x+iy)-f(0)}{x+iy-0}$ but I encountered difficulties dealing with the piecewise function.

How should I approach to solving this kind of piecewise function problem over the complex plane?

Comment: Please edit your post to include the attempt you are mentionning. This might help.

Comment: Prove that this function of two real variables is not differentiable at the origin. (This is stronger than saying it is not derivable as a function of the complex variable.)

Comment: In this context, you have to precise what you mean by derivative? Of the complex variable? Or of two real variables? As your question approach both topics, it is confusing. You use $x+iy$ on one side and $z$ on the other one.

Comment: @AnneBauval fixed

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net I changed it to $x+iy$. but in general i meant that $z=x+iy$.

Comment: @AnneBauval I tried to use  $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}\frac{f(x+iy)-f(0)}{x+iy-0}$ and then convert the limit into $\lim_{r \to 0}$, I ended up with a limit that is depended on $\theta$, but I can't tell what that means in a piecewise  function. I'm looking for the method I need to use when approaching those kind of problems.

Comment: This was your second attempt. But what was the first one (with Cauchy-Riemann equations, i.e. calculation of partial derivatives)?

Comment: I'm not sure how you were able to apply the Cauchy-Riemann equations at $0$. As a hint: I'd try taking the partial derivative along the path $y=x$ since there you simply have that $f(x,x) = \sqrt{x^2} = |x|$.

Comment: @AnneBauval I added my attempt

Comment: You cannot evaluate your expressions at $(x,y)=(0,0)$.. You'd be dividing by zero.

Comment: @AlkaKadri can't I multiply but the denominator first and then evaluate?

Comment: @AnneBauval thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your calculations for the partial derivatives at $(0,0)$
are flawed. The result is always $0$
indeed (so Cauchy-Riemann equations are satisfied, as you said) but this $0$
is not obtained that way. Instead, apply the definition. For instance, $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x,0)-f(0,0)}x=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{0-0}x=0$$
and similarly, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0)=0.$

Therefore, if the differential at $(0,0)$
existed it would be $0$,
so we would have
$$0=\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\left|\frac{f(x,y)-f(0,0)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right|=\lim_{r\to0^+\atop\theta\in\Bbb R}\frac{r\sqrt{|\cos\theta\sin\theta|}}r,$$
which is clearly false.

This proves that $f$ has no differential at $(0,0)$, as a function of two real variables. (A fortiori, as a function of the complex variable, it is not holomorphic at $0$.)

Comment: Thank you for all the help

Answer (score 2):

**Without using Cauchy-Riemann equations**

For $z = t(1+i)$ with $t \ge 0$, you have $f(z)= t$ and therefore

$$\lim\limits_{t \to 0} \frac{f(z) - f(0)}{z} = \frac{1}{1+i}=\frac{1}{2}(1-i)$$

whereas for $z = t$ with $t \gt 0$, you have $f(z)= 0$ and

$$\lim\limits_{t \to 0} \frac{f(z) - f(0)}{z} =0$$

As the two limits are different, $f$ is not holomorphic at $0$.

Comment: Thank you very much